# Best approach to sync data between mobile app cache and the server db?

Tags: database, mobile, synchronization, postgres

I have an offline-first mobile app. The user enters data, data is saved into local SQLite database.
The server has Postgres database. I need to build a two-directional sync strategy that keeps data on the server and on the client in sync. Here's what I want more precisely:

1. Bi-directional sync.
2. Small data volume (hundreds of records).
3. A sync is triggered by events: app opening, record adding/deleting.
4. The database structure is nearly the same on both client and server side.
5. I'm not concerned about conflict resolution. Last write wins strategy will suit my needs.

I was thinking to use timestamps to fetch created/updated/removed from the server side since the last sync. However, I obviously can't rely on the client side timestamps, as the time settings can easily be changed. This will ruin the whole sync process. What is the best approach here?

Comment: @DocBrown thanks for the suggestion! However, as I stated in my question, I'm not concerned about conflict resolution.

Comment: Did you read beyond the title, especially the top answer?

Comment: ... moreover, you may not be interested in how to resolve conflicts *manually* or on an attribute basis, but actually your question *is* essentially about what "last write" means in absence of a single clock - and that is *also* part of conflict resolution, and it is what the accepted answer of that other question is about,

Answer (score 3):

> can't rely on the client side timestamps ... ruin the whole sync process.

I draw the inference that we don't want client to be able to rewrite
yesterday's history, and client has some incentive for such rewrites.

[Lamport clocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport_timestamp)
are a typical way of saying "it's all relative!" in a distributed setting.
I propose a variant.

---

From time to time participants make CRUD updates to a table of interest.
For convenience of reasoning about and verifying behavior,
let us define an **append only** log (file, table, whatever)
which records CRUD details.
Append to the log before making the corresponding change.

In principle we could interleave the two logs by timestamps
to obtain *an* ordering.
Then when each participant replays log entries from
an agreed-upon starting point, maybe "empty table",
they both obtain same table contents.
And automated tests can verify proper behavior.

In many synchronization protocols we see a "sync marker",
"log flush", or similar message that tells us there's
not much skew between the two sides.
Here I propose that server shall send a "time stamp" message
which appears in everyone's log.

Additionally we will find it convenient to occasionally
send and log a "table hash" checksum that summarizes
current rows.

---

Client gets installed and then syncs with server,
so it has a most-recent server timestamp message `t_s`.
It looks at its current time of day and tacks on a `t_c` annotation.
Equivalently it could remember a `delta` annotation of `t_c - t_s`.

Time goes by, and CRUD events happen.
Rather than logging client's raw time of day,
we apply a `delta` correction.
One way to think of this is we log `t_s` followed
by number of elapsed seconds after `t_s` at which the
particular CRUD event happened.

---

Why does this work?
Given that we don't trust the client.

Well, by wall-clock time we see parallel activity
on both client and server with no causal order,
and then we see a "synchronized!" instant.
Then we repeat the somewhat chaotic CRUD activity,
and repeat the synchronization step, alternating between them.

In between syncs, the server fundamentally cannot know
what happened on the client.
That information simply isn't available.
Client can rewrite recent history during such an interval.
So for dishonest client those recent timestamps are
essentially arbitrary.

Each time we sync, client **commits** to its current story.
Client cannot go back to alter it later.

---

After many syncs, feel free to discard week-old logs.
A log entry holds little interest after its sync succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements sound like a precise fit for PowerSync: https://www.powersync.com/

It provides bi-directional sync between Postgres and SQLite. Conflict resolution is customizable but the default implementation results in 'last write wins'.

Disclosure: I am on the PowerSync team.